# Auto suggest when write a character in input field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field. When I click on this input field and write something then it will show all the suggested words that I want.

Like: If I write 'c' then it will show suggested words that i declared 'C#','Code','C++'

HTML:

```
   <input type="text" class="input_field" />
```

How can I do it using JavaScript? Thank you.

Comment: this is what you're looking for http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: search for javascript autocomplete and you will find lots of plugins and tutorials

Comment: you could also use a datalist... https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: always first google, your every problem

Answer (score 0):

Please refer for the auto complete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You may try following. It is my favourite at least.

[Twitter Typeahead JS](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)